# php tags into html tags output

Tags: php

I have this code

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("juliver", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");

$sm = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$sm .= "<li><a href='#".$row['page'].'">'.$row['menulist']."</a></li>";

}

mysql_close($con);

?>
<? echo $sm; ?>
```

My database is look like this.

```
id    menulist          page
1     Home              tb1
2     Gallery           tb2
3     Clothing          tb3
4     Furniture         tb4
5     Household-items   tb5
```

the output should be this if converted into html.

```
<li><a href="#tb1">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#tb2">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#tb3">Clothing</a></li>
<li><a href="#tb4">Furniture</a></li>
<li><a href="#tb5">Household-items</a></li>
```

I tried removing, adding, renaming and etc into the code and etc. but im still stuck and none of them work.

please help me.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting results? Check `mysql_num_rows()`

Comment: maybe, you cannot select db. try this. mysql_select_db("juliver", $con) or die("cannont select: ".nysql_error());

Comment: You need `UL` as parent of `LI`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes seem to be muddled up.
Your literal text should be enclosed in double quotes (since they appear first), and everything else use single quotes:

`$sm .= "<li><a href='#".$row['page']."'>".$row['menulist']."</a></li>";`

results in

`$sm .= "<li><a href='#tb1'>Home</a></li>";`

which you can then output.

You might want to add a `\n` in there as well, to format the output nicely.

`$sm .= "<li><a href='#".$row['page']."'>".$row['menulist']."</a></li>\n";`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be not  open the php_short_tags!